# Why did we only see the N-1 starfighters in one film?

Tags: star-wars, spaceship

I think that this model has a really great design and looks cool and futuristic, but we only saw them in the [Battle of Naboo](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Battle_of_Naboo). I have a lot of questions about that:

- Why don't the Rebels use them?
- Is it exclusive to [Naboo](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Naboo)?
- Is it a bad model in comparison with others fighters like the X-wing or A-wing?
- Were all of them destroyed?

Why don't we see this particular starfighter in any other film?

Comment: *"Why did we only see N-1 starfighters in one film?"* Because the Nth starfighter [got an entire film to himself](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087597/).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It appears to be exclusive to the Naboo and so we wouldn't see it used by the Rebels or other forces outside of the planet. The Star Wars Databank has the following to say:

> **NABOO N-1 STARFIGHTER**
>
> **Protecting the skies and space around Naboo is the N-1 starfighter.** Its sleek design exemplifies the philosophy of art and function witnessed throughout **Naboo technology.** Its twin radial J-type engines are capped in gleaming chrome and trail long delicate-looking finials behind the ship's single-pilot compartment. Behind the pilot sits a standard astromech droid, plugged into an abbreviated, ventrally-fed socket which requires the droid to compress slightly in order to fit within the vessel's curves. The fighter features twin blaster cannons, twin fire-linked torpedo launchers, and a capable automatic pilot feature.
>
> <sub>[Star Wars Databank, NABOO N-1 STARFIGHTER](https://www.starwars.com/databank/naboo-n-1-starfighter)</sub>

The Databank also references its affiliations as *"Galactic Republic, Naboo Royal Guards"* and its only location is *"Naboo"*.

The Databank does, however, note that the Starfighter does also appear in:

- *Star Wars: Episode II Attack of the Clones*. The support vessels for the Naboo Royal Starship in the opening scene are N-1s.

  [image: N-1 Starfighter in the opening scene]
- *Star Wars: Episode VI Return of the Jedi*. These show up as part of the ending montage (in the later edition after Episode 1 was released) and you see them very quickly fly overhead so sorry for the poor image.

  [image: N-1 Starfighters flying over Naboo]
- *Star Wars: The Clone Wars*. They show up in a few episodes and the one below shows quite a few in the background of a hangar scene.

  [image: Lots of N-1s in the background on Naboo]

---

On another note *Incredible Cross-sections of Star Wars, Episode I - The Phantom Menace* has the following description which further emphasises the vehicle is only used by the Naboo.

> [image: Incredible Cross-sections of Star Wars, Episode I - The Phantom Menace, Naboo N-1 Starfighter, relevant parts quoted below]
>
> The single pilot Naboo Royal N-1 Starfighter was developed by the Theed Palace Space Vessel Engineering Crops for the volunteer Royal Naboo Security Forces.
>
> [...]
>
> Found only on Naboo and rarely even there, the N-1, like the Queen's Royal Starship, uses mainly galactic standard components in a custom-built spaceframe that reflects the Naboo people's love of handcrafted, elegant shapes.
>
> [...]
>
> The Naboo being a peaceful people, the Space Fighter Corps is maintained as much through tradition as for military defense, and primarily serves as an honor guard for the Queen's Royal Starship.

Comment: An excellent and well researched answer!

Comment: I guess you could compare them to a (fictional) specific model of lets say, a Rolls Royce, that is only made for the British Royal Family to drive.  You would be unlikely to find one in say... Texas.

Comment: Very nice answer :D

Comment: Interesting... one description says that the astromech droid will "compress" (which doesn't make a whole lot of sense) while the cross section clearly shows the droid actually pulled out of its shell.

Answer (score 19):

For the record, we do see them in several other films.

Padme flies one in *Episode 2: Attack of the Clones*.

and they make a brief appearance in *Return of the Jedi* (2004 cuts onwards).

They also appear in numerous *The Clone Wars* episodes.

---

As to why they're not used by the Rebels, the [Ultimate Star Wars](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ultimate_Star_Wars) factbook indicates that the N-1 was made exclusively by the ...

> [Theed Palace Space Vessel Engineering Corp](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Theed_Palace_Space_Vessel_Engineering_Corps)

... presumably for the sole use of the Naboobian Defence force. Since Naboo wasn't a Rebel-supporting planet and remained firmly in the hands of the Empire until well *after* the death of Palpatine, there's little chance that they'd be making ships available to the Rebellion.

Additionally, the planet had a reputation for being pacifistic and wasn't in the business of arms sales to *either* side.

Answer (score 4):

An N-1's armament is comparable to an A-wing's : 2 laser cannons, 2 launchers (but N-1s have protons torpedoes which are better than an A-wing's concussion missiles). X-wings however beat both of those hands down, with their quad linkable lasers and twin proton torpedo launchers.

The **speed** of these vessels is really the only thing to look at imo (because it was the only thing that really mattered in the game they called *X-Wing*... which was called that for a reason: they're not the *most* armed ships in the fleet, but they are the *best*):

- [A-wing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-wing) :  1,450 kph
- [N-1](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/N-1_starfighter) : 1,100 kph
- [X-wing](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/T-65B_X-wing_starfighter) : 1,050 kph

N-1s can't outrun an ambush by an X-wing, and they can be quickly overtaken by an A-wing. In a stand-up fight verses an A-wing it might be more or less evenly matched, but against an X-wing (pretty much anything except a B-wing; 3 lasers, 3 ion cannons, and torpedoes) would be suicide.

Comment: all speeds are atmospheric because I couldn't find enough data; no MGLT (megalight per hour; sublight space) is listed for the N-1