# How does the N-1 compare to the X-Wing?

Tags: star-wars, the-book-of-boba-fett

In Chapter 5 of the Book of Boba Fett:

> Din Djarin's recently rebuilt and extensively modified N-1 starfighter left two New Republic X-Wings standing.

Dialogue during the episode suggests that this is due to the heavy customisation done to the N-1.

My question is, how much of a difference did those customisations make? Specifically how would a stock pre-Clone Wars N-1 have performed compared to the T65 X-Wing in terms of sublight speed?

Comment: An N-1 would always precede an X-Wing, at least in alphabetical order.

Comment: @lfurini - Unless you include the manufacturer. In which case the Incom T65B X-Wing comes before the Naboo N-1 Starfighter.

Comment: Didn't the X-Wing pilots choose not to follow him?

Comment: @RogueJedi - They explicitly state that he'd gone from their sensor range.

Comment: [Why did we only see the N-1 starfighters in one film?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/208088/23785) - In an atmosphere "N-1s can't outrun an ambush by an X-wing, and they can be quickly overtaken by an A-wing. In a stand-up fight verses an A-wing it might be more or less evenly matched, but against an X-wing (pretty much anything except a B-wing; 3 lasers, 3 ion cannons, and torpedoes) would be suicide." - 1,050 kph X-wings can't catch 1,100 kph N-1s.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the (Canon) [*Star Wars: Ships of the Galaxy*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Ships_of_the_Galaxy) and *[Star Wars: Encyclopedia of Starifighters and Other Vehicles](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Encyclopedia_of_Starfighters_and_Other_Vehicles)* factbooks the Naboobian [N-1 Starfighter](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/N-1_starfighter) has a top sublight speed of **1100kph**. This compares to the [T65B X-Wing Starfighter](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/T-65B_X-wing_starfighter) which has a top speed of **1050kph**.

[image] **vs.** [image]

This suggests that the N-1 in question has been *heavily* customised.

Comment: I have never much spent much thought on the performance metrics of fictional spacecraft. Are these units actual kilometers/miles per hour? Because there are things on wheels that are faster than that, and from the shows I had always imagined spaceships to be a bit more nimble (of course this a galaxy far far away, so maybe their kilometers are longer, or the hours are shorter).

Comment: @EikePierstorff - This is a world in which spaceships are limited to a top speed in atmosphere *and* in space.

Comment: @EikePierstorff And notice that they advertise "speed" rather than "acceleration", which is just hooey for space physics.

Comment: Don't worry, I don't take this too seriously. It is just funny to imagine that a starfighter would be outpaced by an Apollo spacecraft by an order of magnitude (I know, fixed trajectory, so it does not really compare, but still).

Comment: @EikePierstorff - Luke's X-Wing can go from the ground into space straight up, then navigate to a nearby planet using nothing but point-and-shoot. When *you've* got unlimited delta-V, then you can start making remarks about the kph.

Comment: It's already faster; why's that suggest anything, other than it's in pristine condition?

Comment: @Mazura - Because if it pulled away at only 50kph faster, they wouldn't be left in its dust, they'd see it receding relatively slowly with more than adequate time to decide what to do about it.

Comment: Oh, you're presuming they're at speed. I'm presuming they're at slightly above idle. In space....

Comment: @Mazura - That's a fair point. The audio description refers to him "slowing down and levelling off".

Comment: @Mazura - That being said, the X-Wings are astounded by his acceleration, mistaking it for him going to hyperdrive. They show no indication that want (or are capable) of chasing him, so maybe it's his acceleration that's so impressive rather than his top speed.

Comment: *It corners like it's on rails.*

Comment: @Mazura - I wanted him to get out and say "Now *this* is pod-racing"